# Как писать эссе по литературе?

Tags: литература

Можете объяснить, как писать эссе по литературе? Вот у меня тема: духовная драма Катерины по пьессе "Гроза" Островского. Можете написать какой-нибудь шаблон, как писать такие эссе, нам в 10 классе первый раз задали такое сочинение.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

По - русски это называется - краткое сочинение. Лев Толстой оформлял это в виде романов и повестей с рассказами.   В романе "Воскресение" есть Екатерина, главное действующее лицо.

Эссе.

В окружном суде с участием присяжных заседателей слушается дело о похищении денег и отравлении, повлёкшем смерть купца Смелькова. Среди троих обвиняемых в преступлении предстает мещанка Екатерина Маслова, занимающаяся проституцией. Маслова оказывается невиновной, но, в результате судебной ошибки, её приговаривают к четырём годам каторги в Сибири.

краткое описание триллера.

Comment: Что это??? O_o?
Вас просили объяснить, что такое эссе, а не писать его на тему "Льва Толстого"

Answer (score 2):

ЭССЕ́ [сэ́], нескл., ср. (спец.). Прозаическое сочинение небольшого объёма и свободной композиции на частную тему, трактуемую субъективно и обычно неполно.
dic.academic.ru › Толковый словарь Ожегова

Эссе тем и хорошо, что Вы совершенно свободно высказываете и выстраиваете мысли на заданную тему. Строгой формы, строгого плана написания эссе не существует. Главное, не бойтесь, что напишете что-то  неправильно.

Comment: Мне сказали, что сочинение минимум на лист.

Comment: Лист - это небольшое сочинение. Обычное - 2,5 - 3 листа.

Comment: Это ж не "авторский лист"...

Answer (score 1):

hulk29, "эссе", попросту говоря, это вольные мысли на заданную тему (чаще всего - литературную). Т.е. годится все, или почти все, что вам пришло в голову по прочтении данного произведения и хоть как-то связано с заданной темой.
Как верно сказала Екатерина, тут нет правильных и неправильных положений. Если это школьное задание, то должно (по идее) оцениваться ваше умение излагать мысли, а не их соответствие мыслям маститых литературоведов и положениям учебников, ими написанных.

Answer (score 0):

[Подробнее здесь.](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=502.EZ5vUCNHJxeclUpGtScvEHsXQdWUyj4oHOr3GFJk2ih2a4IZWxpdD9egs3Fn5_nUJd_U2M1YjtZcZLnjsSzjOZeedxi3OwfG3t1VBApLYhW_mt48-aUEMpPORTz-3_VcqZjdHbounZNiTatmzZGp9A.18159dfa63c9ed3b2a62e7a42d5bd7d643e590f4&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xti-b8lArfpY2fz6fP4kJz3523BIyRaKdBrJ-E3tDYkBsavJGHcvy-fZ3mW3WhMdwxgbkoT2Y1MCNHRHI7XYWrXMZVtpq3S5P7hdJLyxTh2AnFhm0U4Hv1TU7Kf1tohWqy28jIEoyqkAZVUM_UTuFlUYA_UmgZPcgfRITkm8XfwEdw1qX6GaNDuk4dEmlY7hstBU9ezrWxqiA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxc0JVUTBCYjdBZ19kS0NEU3hSUnZnTXNrQVhlYzRvenhENUxSVnZtbzQwM0VWSU84dGNObG5TZzR5S2RtLVp4dzQwRm1uZUpQTVZZd0tOYVNKeTBJT3FhVWIwSFlBejYyNW1HZlMtaVU1dXk&b64e=2&sign=cb856336782ae179578f3252347e9513&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1415471351310&mc=5.275951980074387)

Comment: Дословно -- AS SAY -- как говорят. Пересказ в чистом виде, можно с ремарками от себя. Жанр "эссе"  это журналистская статья. Сжатое до предела сообщение о событиях -- новостях, чуть-чуть собственно от пишущего. С этих слов и начиналась. 19 век, газеты.  
На западе эссе теперь -- analysis, examination, test/tests, testing, inspection,  trial, что и соответствует школьному заданию, проверка знаний на предмет прочтения книги, знания содержания и описания своими словами сюжета.  
Драма Екатерины в том-то.